# json_decode & file_get_contents doesn't get the UTF8 characters

Tags: php, utf-8

I use

```
$link = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/111866602162732"));
```

the result on that page shows:

```
 "name": "L\u00e9ry, Quebec",
```

I then want to convert that with the accents.. like this:

```
$location_name = $link->name;
echo 'NAME ORIGINAL: '.$location_name;
$location_name = preg_replace('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $location_name); // convert to UTF8
echo '  NAME after: '.$location_name;
```

I get the following result:

```
  NAME ORIGINAL: LÃ©ry, Quebec     NAME after: LÃ©ry, Quebec
```

my preg_replace is correct, so it's the original name that is being transformed by the file_get_contents.

Comment: Could you please explicitly ask a question? Its unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Whats your expected Name ?

Comment: I need to have the accents... result should be Léry, Quebec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `file_get_contents` don't give you back a well format UTF-8 text, then json_decode you would return NULL. Json MUST be in UTF-8 encoding.

> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings. ([json_decode](http://php.net/manual/it/function.json-decode.php))

So, I guess that you're reading the data with another encoding. Check it out.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by another encoding... my code is written above...

Comment: Seems that you're reading a utf-8 string with another charset. Be sure to read the data with the correct charset. See for http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html#http-related

Comment: just put `header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );` at the top of your code, then read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you're treating a valid UTF-8 output given to you by json_decode as ISO-8859-1
See here, for example: http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-utf-8-latin1.html

Make sure that you're treating your debug output as UTF-8 - that should solve the problem.

Comment: you're right, that seems to be my problem, but how do I treat my debug output as UTF-8?

Comment: Well... it depends - if you're viewing it in a browser, make sure you have either `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` or proper `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` header.

Comment: If you're working in CLI then everything suddenly becomes much more painful and specific to the shell/terminal you're using :)